# I installed android studio and I created my first project and facing this error... I clicked all links but nothings happened

Tags: java, android, maven, kotlin, gradle

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2.
Searched in the following locations:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.2/gradle-4.2.2.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.2/gradle-4.2.2.pom
  Required by:
  project :
  Add google Maven repository and sync project
  Open File

Comment: The first link actually points to an existing pom file. Have you tried rerunning the build and are you sure that the Java version used to run Android Studio has internet access?

Comment: I tried nothing happened , I received the same error!